# Any way I can get hold of which button I have pressed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uiimage

Is there any way I can get hold of which button I have pressed?

The buttons are created programmatically using a for loop.

I have a scroll-view of images (i used buttons for the images) where the images are taken by the user from the camera. So after the user takes a picture, the "new" picture will appear in the scrollview with the "old" pictures. The pictures are shrink into smaller sizes so what I want is that when I click the button (of any image) the image will pop up in another view in the actual size.

The button of images is created using a for loop. However, I do not know how to get hold of which button the user press. For now, when i press the button (regardless of which image/button), the last picture that is taken will always show up.

Thanks for you time.

Comment: you explained your question in a good way...But it is always better if you add a bit of code segment of the related section so that people here can easily understand where you are getting stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tag property of button.

When you create the button, put a tag to each image buttons.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < your_no_images ; i++){
  UIButton *button = [UIButton <yourbuttontype>];
 -----
  button.tag   = i;
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [yourView addSubView:button];
}
```

Now in the button click action..

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender{
   //if you has an array of UIImage's
   UIImage *clickedImage = (UIImage *)[yourImageArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply(: However my app crashes when it reaches the button click action it crashes.

Comment: put a break point in buttonClicked function and see if it gets executed

Comment: It was a small typo mistake i made. The code works fine! Thank you so much for your help(:

Answer (score 0):

IBAction methods, like those triggered upon clicking a button, include a `sender` argument. `sender` is the object that triggered the action, for example the button that was clicked. Like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonWasClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"The %@ button was clicked", (UIButton *)sender.currentTitle);
}
```

Comment: OP explains in the question that he/she creates buttons programatically in a for loop..There is no Interface Builder or IBACtion there

Comment: IBAction is really just void anyway. It's only a hint to IB. The method I posted will work just the same for programmatically created buttons as it does for buttons created in Interface Builder. The relevant part of the answer is the `sender` argument.